# How to get rid of file extensions (.CSV) in a file name that is generated by R

Tags: r, csv, filenames

I have a series of .csv files in my working folder and I wrote a code to get them all, do everything I want to do with them and, in the end, write the result in another file adding "_pp" to the original file name:

```
random <- grep(".csv",list.files(), fixed=TRUE)                             
files <- list.files()[random]   
for (igau in 1:length(files))                                               
{
(.......)
file <- paste("H:/METEO_data/AEMET_2/",files[igau],"_pp.csv",sep="")
write.table(d,file,row.names=TRUE, col.names=NA, sep=" ")                   
}
```

the problem is that I get "3059.csv_pp.csv" when what I wanted was "3059_pp.csv". Is there a way of taking the first .csv out?

thanks

Comment: Tip: use `seq_along(files)` instead of `1:length(files)`. When no files found then first is `numeric(0)` (and loop do nothing) and second is `1:0=c(1,0)` and you got random effects (e.g. in your case it will write two files: `"H:/METEO_data/AEMET_2/NA_pp.csv"` and `"H:/METEO_data/AEMET_2/_pp.csv"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first two lines can be simplified to one `list.files` call that uses the `pattern` argument.  Then you can change the output file name using `gsub`.

```
files <- list.files(pattern=".csv")
for(i in 1:length(files)) {
  outFile <- file.path("H:/METEO_data/AEMET_2",
                       gsub(".csv", "_pp.csv", files[igau]))
  write.table(d, outFile, row.names=TRUE, col.names=NA, sep=" ")
}
```

You could also loop over the elements in `files`, but that assumes you don't need the `igau` index for anything else.  And in order to potentially avoid confusing yourself in the future, you may want to avoid using `file` for variable names because it's base package function that opens a connection to a file.

```
for(File in files) {
  outFile <- file.path("H:/METEO_data/AEMET_2",
                       gsub(".csv", "_pp.csv", File))
  write.table(d, outFile, row.names=TRUE, col.names=NA, sep=" ")
}
```

Comment: To cover all weird cases there should be `list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")` (`.` means "any character") and `sub("\\.csv$", "_pp.csv", File))`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `files[igau]` contains the `.csv` extension. You'll have to do something like this:

```
basefile <- strsplit(files[igau], ".")
file <- paste("H:/METEO_data/AEMET_2/",basefile[0],"_pp.csv",sep="")
```

`basefile[0]` will contain everything before the first `.`. This means that this code will break if you have filenames with dots in them (i.e. `3059.2.csv`). If this is the case, then you'll have to `paste()` together everything in `basefile` except for the last element, which will be the `csv` that you're trying to get rid of.

Comment: I decided to try the gsub so the filenames with dots wouldn't be a problem, but thank you anyway for answering